# WCF, how do I instantialize all objects in a DataContract? [OnDeserializing] does not work

Tags: c#, wcf, deserialization

So I have some code like this.

```
[DataContract]
public class Example
{
    SomeClass _someVar;

    [OnDeserializing]
    public void OnDeserializing(StremingContext c)
    {
        _someVar = new SomeClass();
    }
}
```

Here is the funny thing, OnDeserializing() gets called if I use the test debugging client from Visual Studio 2010. But if I try and host my WCF service and then call it from my own client it doesn't get called (or probably doesn't), because _someVar is always null.

Argh!

What else do I need to do?

Kind regards,
Fugu

Comment: I've looked into Partial Trust after your suggestion and couldn't find anything that helped. I tried everything suggested for Partial Trust environments and it has had no effect sadly. This is actually driving me insane.

Comment: you try to call OnDeserializing(...) on server side or client side ?

Comment: I did not know I had an option? I believe it would be server-side as there is no facility to transport code down the pipe to a client, only data? Is there something I explicitly need to do here to ensure the server executes the code and instantiates the class(es)? I have tried OnSerializing() but it never gets called.

Answer (score 2):

WCF does not use standard .net serialization, so I'm not certain it will invoke your OnDeserializing method.  However you can ask WCF to use an XmlSerializer, which should give you the behavior you want.  Have a look at "Controlling the Serialization Process" [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732038.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Further to PaulF's answer, your class is not a singleton - 2 calls to the service will by default instantiate `Example` twice and call the method once.

Because of this, there's really very little point in having any variables declared at a class level.

If you want to change this behaviour, have a look [here](http://www.larswilhelmsen.com/2008/12/11/codename-velocity-wfwcf-persistence-provider/) for more information